# What are the weaknesses and shortcomings of arrays?

Tags: java

I would like to know what are the weaknesses of the arrays. I think that it is very helpful to know in order to determine whether the arrays are the best way to store the data in particular situation, or to predict the time of execution.

**Edit 1:** Clarification, by arrays as I understand them:

1. Not **finite**, but **fixed size storage**, that is used as **sequential data containers**, that are **mutable**. 1 or more **indexes** are used to **reference** a specific data container.

   1. Data contained must be of **same type**, if the type is **primitive**.
   2. Data contained must be of **same data type** or **descendant** of the type, if type is object (this is **polymorphism**), this kind of type **conversion** is **narrower to wider** also called **covariant** conversion.
   3. **All arrays** in Java are **1 dimensional arrays**.
   4. **Swapping** elements or **finding element with its indexes** is **fast** operation
   5. **Adding/Removing** elements is **slow** operation, as array is recreated
   6. **Element types** are **enforced** at runtime, this is called arrays are **reified**.
   7. Java array methods are in `java.util.Arrays` and thy do not even contain basic array manipulation methods like **union** and **intersection**. Its sad, that guava-libraries is not part of standard Java.
   8. Object array is filled with **references** to storage locations where the data actually is.
2. **Array of arrays** is called **2 dimensional array**.

   1. 2d arrays first array is filled with **references** to other arrays.
   2. Other arrays are not stored sequentially.
   3. Other arrays can vary in element size, this is called **ragged**- and **jagged arrays**.
   4. Java arrays have **row-major order**.
   5. Array **dimension** is typically **limited to 255**, but it varies from implementation.
3. Exceptions and important notes.

   1. In case of managed memory environment, the **absolute locations** of data elements **can be sequential**, but most likely are not.
   2. Arrays used directly can't be **threadsafe**, **immutable** or **have transactional integrity** and because of this, there is no direct way to go **parallel**.
   3. If you need to find if specific data is contained in **sorted array** you can use **binary search**, that is not much slower then **hashset.contains** what I assume uses **VMMemoryManager.getIdentityHashCode**, that is basically just old school **modulation calculus** and where **collisions can happen**.
   4. Java **generics** is just **compiler magic**, but if you want to use **Java generic** with arrays, then you can't use **primitive types**.
   5. In Java 6, **Collections.sort()** works like - dump data in array and ... - at that point difference is x2 times in memory.
   6. **Garbage collector** really does not like arrays, and thy usually end up in **old generation**, and wont be freed any soon.
   7. It's a bad idea to enter **big** data **elements** in arrays, but i can't remember why.

   In my opinion arrays are one of very best ways to store data, just not directly. At times, my head seems to be like a garbage bin, where knowledge is malformed. This is one reason why I asked this question - to confirm what i know.

Comment: Weakness - when compared to which other data structure?

Comment: I assume Arrays.comparedTo(? extends data_structure), and that arrays are fixed size mutable sequential storage. Interested as of java 6 and not 1.5.

Comment: You want us to enumerate all data structures in our answer? Would you consider it helpful if I listed "infinite arrays are impossible" as disadvantage when compared to lazy-created lists? Anyway, do as you like; I'm outta here.

Comment: @meriton: "The Wisdom of Crowds: Why the Many Are Smarter Than the Few" - i assume that it's like bubble-sort, eventually good answers bubble up.

Comment: I have to read that last comment as an admission that you *don't even know what the question is*. For this question to have any meaning--- *any* at all ---it must have a context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java5, arrays are very rarely the best way to store data - generic collections are almost always superior:

- generic elements (especially with wildcards) bring type safety and flexibility - you can use not only `List<T>` but `List<? extends T>` and `List<? super T>`, as opposed to `T[]` (which corresponds to the second of the three variants, not the first)
- subtyping for generics is *invariant*, which in brief means that e.g. a `List<String>` is *not* a `List<Object>` - this saves you from a lot of runtime exceptions, because the compiler can detect them and give error messages
- arrays are fixed size, collections can dynamically resize themselves as needed
- collections come in lots of different flavors, with distinct capabilities, useful for different scenarios - e.g. linked list, queue, map, set. Arrays can be usually directly replaced by `ArrayList`, but if you need associative, ordered, prioritized, unique-value, thread-safe, immutable etc. storage, you would be hard pressed with an array
- collections have several useful methods, e.g. `contains`
- you can only create arrays of *reifiable* types - i.e. you can't create a `List<String>[]`

Comment: +1 For mentioning covariance - invariance

Answer (score 4):

You ought also to know the strengths of arrays, and there are a couple.

- Arrays of primitive types typically take significantly less space per element than collections of the corresponding wrapper types.  This is partly due to the overhead of the wrapper objects (depending on how they are created), and partly due to the fact that a JVM typically stores booleans, bytes, chars and shorts 2, 4 or 8 to a machine word in an array.
- Arrays of all types have a smaller per-array space overhead than collection types.  For example, an ArrayList is really an array of objects wrapped in another object with 2 fields.
- Array access and update is a bit faster than the equivalent collection `get` and `set` operations.

Now, these space / performance differences are not usually worth worrying about.  (The flexibility and convenience of collections outweighs them.)  However, in some data intensive applications these differences can be significant.

Answer (score 3):

Probably easiest to compare them against the advantages of alternatives:

**vs. `ArrayList<T>`**
Much more convenient to add and remove elements.  Excepting adding at the end, most operations just as slow (and fast) as arrays.

**vs. `LinkedList<T>`**
Much faster to add and remove elements, extremely slow for getting elements by index.

**vs `HashSet<T>`**
Much faster `contains`, `add`, and `remove` operations.  Lose element ordering.

**vs `HashMap<TKey, TValue>`**
Allows you to quickly access the element by a means other than an index.  Lose element ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Overall weaknesses:

- Fixed length. Length of an array is declared at initialisation, and can't be changed after that.
- Arrays use `int` as index. No array can contain more than `2^31 - 1` elements
- You can't create an immutable array
- You can't create generic arrays

Comment: Actually, a Collection cannot contain more than `2^31 - 1` elements either ... due to the signatures of some of the methods; e.g. `size()`.

Comment: A collection actually CAN contains more than `2^21 - 1` elements. This case is even covered by the Javadoc: "If this collection contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE" (documentation of the `Collection.size()` method.